# Should syrup or pastry be cooled when pouring on to Baklava?

Tags: dessert, pastry, middle-eastern-cuisine, turkish-cuisine

When making Baklava, should you let the syrup or pastry cool before pouring the syrup over pastry?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the formula:

**Sheet baklawa with nuts:** Boiled syrup is poured on top after tray is out of oven for 2-3 minutes.

**Pieces / rolled baklawa with nuts:** Room temperature syrup is sprinkled / brushed on top after tray is out of oven for 2-3 minutes.

**Sheet baklawa with cream/ashta:** Cold syrup is sprinked / brushed on top after tray is out of oven for 2-3 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

The pastry should be cool, but the syrup should be neither hot nor cool - it should be lukewarm. If it's too cold, it will be too thick and difficult to pour, and it if it's too hot, it may run or damage the pastry. I usually allow mine to sit for 10-15 minutes, until I can comfortably place my pinky finger inside it.

Answer (score 0):

The rule I distinctly remember about Baklava (and most middle eastern pastry) is that one has to be hot while the other cool. So if the Baklava is hot, the syrup should be cool. Or vice versa.